# My code for displaying suggestions works fine with Firefox but not for Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, onblur, onkeyup

The function is supposed to load up suggestions based on what the user would enter on the textbox.

onkeyup and onblur events should have the textbox evaluated then the result will be fed to an initially hidden div which prior to feeding the data will be shown first.

Initially those events were included in the  tag which works fine for firefox.

As an alternative i tried removing the event from the tag and used jQuery $() selector to tie up the event to the function which makes it does not work on any browser right after.

This is the code that works for firefox but not on IE and chrome.

```html
<td align="center">
    <input type='text' size='25' id='dr' name='dr' style="width: 45px" onkeyup='drKeyUpFunction(this.value);' onblur='drBlurFunction();'>
    <div id='drSuggestions' class='suggestionsBox' style='display: none'>
        <div id='drSuggestionsList' class='suggestionList'></div>
    </div>
</td>

<td align="center">
    <input type='text' size='25' id='outExpense' name='outExpense' style='width: 85px' onkeyup='expKeyUpFunction(this.value);' onblur='expBlurFunction();'>
    <div id='expSuggestions' class='suggestionsBox' style='display: none'>
        <div id='expSuggestionsList' class='suggestionList'></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

```
function drKeyUpFunction(dr_num=''){
    if (dr_num.length == 0){ $('#drSuggestions').hide();
    } else {
        $.post("post_dr.php", {string: "" + dr_num + ""}, function(data){
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $('#drSuggestions').show();
                $('#drSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}

function drBlurFunction(thisValue='', thatValue='', anotherValue=''){
    $('#dr').val(thisValue);
    $('#drcust').html(thatValue);
    $('#drbal').html(anotherValue);
    setTimeout("$('#drSuggestions').hide();", 200);
}

function expKeyUpFunction(expense=''){
    if (expense.length == 0){ $('#expSuggestions').hide();
    } else {
        $.post("post_expense.php", {string: "" + expense + ""}, function(data){
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $('#expSuggestions').show();
                $('#expSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}

function expBlurFunction(thisValue=''){
    $('#outExpense').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#expSuggestions').hide();", 200);
}
```

As an alternative i removed the events in the input tag and placed these jQuery selectors on the js file housing the functions but they don't work anymore after I placed them.

```
$('#dr').keyUp(drKeyUpFunction(this.value)).blur(drBlurFunction());
$('#outExpense').keyUp(expKeyUpFunction(this.value)).blur(expBlurFunction());
```

Whats expected out of this code is a div showing up available suggestions across all browsers.

I would greatly appreciate it if you can help me out.

Comment: Have you checked the error in the console that you are getting. Please post the error that you are getting in chrome and IE.

Comment: Your jQuery version is invoking the functions immediately and `this` isn't what you think it is. Also when passing strings to `setTimeout` first argument they are supposed to evaluate to function references not arbitrary code to run. Use anonymous functions to solve both issues

Comment: @JayotiParkash the error in Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLInputElement.event for Chrome. function is undefined for edge.

Comment: Make sure that you pass the necessary arguments of a function when you call it. If you do not pass it than it nay cause this kind of error.

Comment: thanks @Deepak-MSFT, I've reverted back to the previous working firefox code and  I've changed the code a bit for it not to get errors if there is no value entered. But its still not working for Chrome and IE/Edge only firefox.

Comment: From the HTML code I can see that you did not pass any parameters while you call the functions. So it is better to pass the dummy value if there is no value available to pass. Instead of changing the function declaration.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT you mean like this `<input type='text' size='25' id='dr' name='dr' style="width: 45px"  value='dummy' onkeyup='drKeyUpFunction(this.value);' onblur='drBlurFunction();'>`. Tried it its still not working for bot chrome and IE/Edge

Comment: Pass the argument in drBlurFunction();. This function has 3 parameters and try to remove the empty value from the function declaration.

Comment: Like this `<input type='text' size='25' id='dr' name='dr' style="width: 45px" onkeyup='drKeyUpFunction(this.value);' onblur='drBlurFunction("dummy1","dummy2","dummy3");'>` and yup already removed the declaration just didn't edit the one above. Still not working for Chrome and IE though

Comment: I try to it on my side and it looks like function get called. You need to check on which line it get stuck. Try to put the break point in your JS code from developer tools and try to debug it line by line may help to find the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I followed your suggestion to put break points via chrome or IE. When i open the js file via Dev tools of both browser the functions are not there, weird. You happen to know what's going on?

Comment: It can be possible that you had added reference to the multiple JS files on your page and you was checking wrong file so you did not see that function. If this is not the case and if it is possible to share the link than you can share the link of that page here. we will also try to find that function and check the issue with it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT thanks for the the insight. I already figured it out. Both browser cached the js file when it was empty so what i did was cleared all cache and cookies and when i checked it again its there and its working for both of them now